# How to create repeatable content sections

Tags: umbraco7

I've just recently started using Umbraco and find it a little confusing with terminology - I've managed to create pages and create templates to pull in for like footer and navigation. however what I am looking to achieve is to add a custom section which the end user can just add many times on one page which includes parameters such as background-color, title, paragraph, image, image alignment and text alignment.

I've been reading things such as macro's and trying to look at youtube videos but dont seem to find anything that gives me the right direction to implementing this. I'm assuming a macro is the right way. I just need it to be simple for a non-developer to come in and be able to add/remove/edit a section. I'm also hoping this method is also possible on multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options for repeatable sections in Umbraco. The main main built in one is the Grid. The grid allows you to create and configure relatable blocks that you can use on a page, like say a title block, an image block etc. Out of the box it uses bootstrap markup, but you can change that if you want. More details on the grid here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout

Next up are the plugin options. The two main ones for what you're after are Nested Content (which is now a part of the core in the late version of Umbraco): https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/ this works a bit like the grid, except you create DocTypes to represent your blocks of content, and you have to write your own view templates from scratch.

Similar to Nested Content, but also slightly different, is Stacked Content: https://github.com/umco/umbraco-stacked-content this is similar to Nested Content in that you must write your own views etc.

Comment: I discovered Archetype which is similar to what I needed to achieve - but this is more ideal as Archetype has ceased development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to change a few things on top of a 'template' that each page would utilise, I would recommend making use of a **[Master Template](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/creating-basic-site/creating-master-template-part-1)**. This allows you to inherit the properties from the base file, and add your own properties in the child template that would overwrite the base. Note that you can have multiple master templates on a single site. For example, I have some pages that I don't want to show the banner on, so I use a second master template for these pages.

However, the downside of making use of master templates is that the admin would need access to the `Templates` (under the `Settings` section) in order to make changes.

If you're looking to allow an admin to choose which 'partials' are included on the page, you're looking for the **[Multinode Treepicker](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/multinode-treepicker)**. This allows you to choose which nodes are shown on the page, right from the `Content` section (which is much safer for admins to modify). Note that it says it is obsolete, but is still available in Umbraco 7 (and what I personally am using).

The multinode treepicker can select either individual nodes to display under certain circumstances, or loop over all chosen nodes by the admin in the `Content` section.

This can be done either **typed**:

```
@{
    var typedMultiNodeTreePicker = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("banner");
    foreach (var item in typedMultiNodeTreePicker)
    {
        <p>@item.Name</p>
    }
}
```

Or **dynamically**:

```
@{
    var bannerList = CurrentPage.banner.ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var bannerCollection = Umbraco.Content(bannerList);
    foreach (var item in bannerCollection)
    {
        <p>@item.Name</p>
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)